# socket.io can join a room but cannot leave a room

Tags: express, websocket, socket.io

I am building a basic chatroom service using express and socket.io and I am running into an issue where I can join but cannot leave a room.

```
io.on('connection', (client) => {
  client.on('login', (msg) => {
    room_name = 'room'+msg.id

    console.log('login', room_name);

    var room = io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[room_name];
    var numClients = room ? room.length : 0;
    console.log('number of clients', numClients);

    client.join(room_name)
  });

  client.on('logout', (msg) => {
    room_name = 'room'+msg.id
    console.log('logout', room_name)

    var room = io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[room_name];

    client.leave(room_name, function(err) {
      var room_t = io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[room_name];
      if (room_t) {
        console.log("after leaving - room", room_t)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

From the front-end, I know that the socket emits are being correctly transmitted, because I get both the 'login' and 'logout' console log statements. However, in the `client.on('logout')`, I do not seem to be correctly leaving the room. Whenever I look at the console log statements for number of clients in the room, it never seems to be decreasing, as I would expect after leaving. Further, after checking the `console.log("after leaving - room", room_t)` statement, `room_t` contains all of the old information about the room (showing that the client has in fact NOT left the room). I get the same results if I do `client.leave(room)` and `client.leave(room_name)`. (I have made sure that the room_names are the same for both login and logout)

An interesting thing is that I can leave the room immediately after joining. For example, in `client.on(login)`, if I join the room then immediately leave the room, then I have no issue at all doing that. Not sure what is going on there.

Thanks in advance!

Versions:

- Python 3.7.6
- node v13.12.0
- express 4.17.1
- socket.io@2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that it's a bug that's more about 8 year's old that socket.io never bothered to fix.

You can see it here as a git issue: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/463

The client is actually disconnected.

The way you should use to check the client is like the following:

```js
//Put this under the io.on('connection' ....

io.clients((error, clients) => {

  if (error) throw error;

  console.log(clients); 

// => [6em3d4TJP8Et9EMNAAAA, G5p55dHhGgUnLUctAAAB]
//It should give you an array of connected client with thier socket.id

});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it is still not letting my client leave the room :(

Comment: What way do you use to determine if the client has disconnected or not?

Comment: I am listing the number of clients joined to the room (room.length) and that number does not seem to decrease ever.

Comment: I'll add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it out but it doesn't solve my use case....

Basically, how would I be able to tell when the specific user has "logged out"? I want to keep track of who is in the room and has gone out of the room at any given moment

Comment: The `io.clients` in the sample will give you an array of unique ids that are then associated with the users. So you can use that to determine if someone has logged out at a given moment

Comment: However, you will have to employ a full-blow auth system if you want to link the id to a user all the time when he or she logs in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
client.on('leave', (room) => {
  client.rooms.forEach((room) => {
    client.leave(room)
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.